# Do Android AppLinks require a production release of App?

Tags: android, google-play, branch.io, applinks

I am working on integrating Android Applinks into my application. I have successfully integrated deeplinking via branch.io and uri schemes to take a user into my application when installed. I am now trying to get AppLinks to work and to take the user to the Play Store if the app is not installed. Currently this is not working so I am trying to rule out variables. Specifically, I am testing AppLinks with an App on Closed-Alpha via the developer console.

Should I expect AppLinks to work if I am testing the App on a non-production release?

**Note:** I am able to access the app via the appstore on my Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here. To answer your specific question:

**No, it is not necessary for the version of the app in the Play Store to support App Links.** In fact, it is not even necessary to have the app in the Play Store at all.

This sounds like a configuration problem, but it's impossible to debug without more information. Feel free to post additional details here, or reach out to the Branch [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) for assistance!

Comment: Thanks. This was the exact answer I was looking for. I suspected it had to do with my configuration, but, being as this process is new to me I wanted to be able to rule out the App Store piece. I will do some more debugging on my end and reach out to the integrations team if my efforts are fruitless.

Comment: No problem at all! Our Integrations team usually responds within a few hours, so get in touch any time :)